# recieving an [ng:areq] error with a simple AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a simple Angular application that iterates over the data in my JSON and renders it on the template. i am recieving the foll ng:areq error and im unable to quite comprehend the problem. any help wld be appreciated.

```
    GET http://localhost:8080/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js 
angular.js:13236 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'classifiedsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=classifiedsCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at assertArg (angular.js:1825)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1835)
    at angular.js:9831
    at setupControllers (angular.js:8852)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8898)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8226)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8106)
    at angular.js:1696
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16925bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1694invoke @ angular.js:4604doBootstrap @ angular.js:1692bootstrap @ angular.js:1712angularInit @ angular.js:1606(anonymous function) @ angular.js:30423trigger @ angular.js:3108defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3398eventHandler @ angular.js:3386
```

the foll is the json structure. i have checked the validity of my json using an online json formatter tool.

```
    {
"name": "George Eliot",
"thoughts": ["A man likes to assume superiority over himself, by holdin up his bad example and sermonizing on it.", "A man conscious of enthusiasm for worthy aims is sustained under petty hostilities by the memory of great workers who had to fight their way not without wounds, and who hover in his mind as patron saints invisibly helping.", "Life must be taken up on a lower stage of expectation.", "One has a grudge against a man who carries off the prettiest girl in the town.", "The growing good of the world is partly dependent on unhistoric acts; and that things are not so ill with you and me as they might have been is half owing to the number who lived faithfully a hidden life, and rest in unvisited tombs."]

}
```

the foll is a snapshot of the template:

```
<body ng-app="ngClassifieds" ng-controller="classifiedsCtrl">


<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <p><strong>ngMasters</strong></p>

    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<md-content class="md-padding" layout="column" layout-wrap>

    <md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds" flex-xs="100" flex-gt-sm="60">

        <md-card-content>
            <div class="classified-info">

                <h2 class="md-display-2">{{ classified.name }}</h2>

                <ul> 
                    <li ng-repeat="thought in classified.thoughts">{{ thought }}</li>

                </ul>  

            </div>



        </md-card-content>


    </md-card>


</md-content>
```

the foll is the controller:

```
    (function(){

"use strict";

angular
    .module("ngClassifieds")
    .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope) {

        $scope.classifieds = [

{
"name": "George Eliot",
"thoughts": ["A man likes to assume superiority over himself, by holdin up his bad example and sermonizing on it.", "A man conscious of enthusiasm for worthy aims is sustained under petty hostilities by the memory of great workers who had to fight their way not without wounds, and who hover in his mind as patron saints invisibly helping.", "Life must be taken up on a lower stage of expectation.", "One has a grudge against a man who carries off the prettiest girl in the town.", "The growing good of the world is partly dependent on unhistoric acts; and that things are not so ill with you and me as they might have been is half owing to the number who lived faithfully a hidden life, and rest in unvisited tombs."]

}



]

    });

})();
```

Comment: could you check out developer console to look at `classifieds.ctr.js ` is loaded or not.. seems like controller haven't attached to `ngClassifieds` module

Comment: @Pankaj the foll is error i am receieving: http://imgur.com/qz2nWdw

Comment: make sure you refer correct path of `classifieds.ctr.js`

Comment: yes, i have included it in my index. html `<script src="components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js"></script>`

Comment: could you add your folder structure image, so that I can guide you to resolve your issue..

Comment: sure. here it is, http://imgur.com/3QMpQwB

Comment: aah.. i had got my folder strucute wrong in the script tag. thanks Pankaj.. i think the data's comin thru now.. thanks for the direction.

Comment: Glad to know that.. Thanks :-)